# Custom table columns

Tags: tables, columns

[image]

trying to figure out how to make these tables in overleaf. The splitted column on top is the thing causing me trouble.

Comment: Make normal tables and rotate them.

Comment: this is just the way the picture was inputted into the system, im trying too create a 2 columned header, but split the 1st column in 2

Comment: What you try so far? On image are shown two simple tables in parallel. For "INPUT" is used multi column cell: `\multicolumn{2}{c}{INPUT}`. For more information how to write tables see https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables, for your case section *Columns spanning multiple rows*.

Comment: \begin{table}[H] %I put the [H] here. it means "be here"
\centering
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|} 
    \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{INPUT} & OUTPUT
     $V_{DD}$& $V_{I}$ 
     \hline\hline
     5 & 0.0  \\  
     5 & 0.5  \\ 
     5 & 1.0  \\
     5 & 1.5  \\
     \hline
    \end{tabular}
\caption{TABLE }
\label{tab: table name}
\end{table}

Comment: Maybe for the future read and follow this post: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/. This makes it easier for you and others. In addition, consider accepting the provided answers for your previous questions.

Answer (score 3):

```
\sffamily
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textbf{INPUT}} & \textbf{OUTPUT} \\ \hline
A                 & B                & A NAND B        \\ \hline
0                 & 0                & 1               \\ \hline
0                 & 1                & 1               \\ \hline
1                 & 0                & 1               \\ \hline
1                 & 1                & 0               \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\quad %
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textbf{INPUT}} & \textbf{OUTPUT} \\ \hline
A                 & B                & A AND B         \\ \hline
0                 & 0                & 0               \\ \hline
0                 & 1                & 0               \\ \hline
1                 & 0                & 0               \\ \hline
1                 & 1                & 1               \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In case you don't want rotation just use `\multicolumn` for splitting the column.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[]
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
            \hline
            \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{INPUT} & OUTPUT  \\ \hline
            A            & B            & A AND B \\ \hline
            0            & 0            & 1       \\ \hline
            0            & 1            & 1       \\ \hline
            1            & 0            & 1       \\ \hline
            1            & 1            & 0       \\ \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1: I edited the text, Daine will automatically get a notification when you provide an answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is the table you are looking for (without any rotation}

[image: R]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}    
\sffamily
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2} % adjust to expand the cells vertically
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\bfseries INPUT} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\bfseries OUTPUT} \\ \hline
    A & B   & A NAND B  & A AND B  \\ \hline
    0 & 0   & 1         & 0         \\ \hline
    0 & 1   & 1         & 0         \\ \hline
    1 & 0   & 1         & 0         \\ \hline
    1 & 1   & 0         & 1         \\ \hline
\end{tabular}   
    
\end{document}
```